# Is there any way to use data frame by matching it with value in list in R?

Tags: c#, r

I have a list "data" with only one value - the name of data frame (I got it as an argument passed from the external C# application - I choose a data frame from list in app to show its structure):

```
args <- commandArgs()
data <- args[2]
> data
[1] "NskData"
```

Next I need to operate with exact this data frame. For example to build a plot or to show a structure. But the question is: how to refer to this data frame? This way won't work:

```
> str(data)
 chr "NskData"
```

In other words - I need to see structure of NskData, so the result will be from:

```
str(NskData)
```

Maybe there is a way to refer to data frame by index? I tried matching the char with dataframes, I can get the index of TRUE value, but the main question still remains.

Comment: Use `get` - `get(data)`.

Comment: @RonakShah, thank you so much! I have almost wrote neural network by using "if" operators, but you solved my problem so easily!